# Should peer review of conference proceedings be listed in a CV with journal peer reviewing, or should it be separate?

Tags: peer-review, cv

In my field, conferences are rarely peer reviewed.  The usual categories of peer review are journals and grants.  If I peer review for conference proceedings, should I list that in my CV under journal peer reviewing, or should I create a new category?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can go with a broader heading so you can group them all together - something like "Manuscript Reviewing" will cover a myriad of publication categories, like conference proceedings, journals, edited volumes, etc. EDIT: Would also add that in doing so, the reader would then automatically know that those are all peer-reviewed venues.

Answer (score 0):

**A *service* section would be appropriate**, optionally with sub-sections including *editor*, *editorial board*, and *PC*, for instance. Service goes beyond peer-review, so you could also have sub-sections including *examiner*, for example.

Comment: Can someone explain the negative vote for this answer? I think it's the answer, although I would suggest "Academic Services" as the header.

Comment: @Coder +1 _professional service_ or _professional activities_ work too, the title _service_ may not be the best

Comment: What does the abbreviation "PC" stand for?

Comment: PC = program committee